# HSV image formation in python

Tags: python

I have 3 (512×512) numpy arrays representing the Hue, Saturation and Value channels of my desired HSV image, containing float values.

How do I construct a single 512×512 image from these 3 numpy arrays?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide the
[shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
also make sure to provide some input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: You mention you want to construct a (512*512) image, however HSV images have 3 channels (so a shape of (512, 512, 3)). Are you asking how to combine your 3 arrays into a single image of this shape?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that these 3 arrays represents the HSV channels of the final image . I don't know how to form the final image

Answer (score 0):

To create an HSV image from the 3 channels, you can put them in a numpy array and [transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) it to convert the shape from (3, 512, 512) to (512, 512, 3):

```py
hsv = np.transpose([h, s, v], (1, 2, 0))
```

With OpenCV you can also use [`cv2.merge`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4).

Comment: Thanks very much, by the way I'm sorry . Do you know how to realize or display the final image in ideal HSV[0:360,0:1,0:1] values because the current values are float and the image is ugly

Comment: You can display the image using [matplotlib.pyplot.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) for example. It supports float values but expects the image to be in RGB format. You can convert it to RGB using the OpenCV library: `cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)`.